# How to backup mssql database on docker

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm running mssql server windows developer editon on docker, and I'll like to backup my database, so that every time I spin up a container, I don't have to recreate my databases and Re-Bootstrap. I've tried mounting a volume to my physical system, I keep getting the error

> container aa8b9.. encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified.

The command I used was

```
docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e sa_password=testing1234 -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer -v "C:\test\Microsoft SQL Server":"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\"
```